# avoiding the spaces and lines while reading text file in c++

Tags: c++

if I got in a text file numbers like this

1.1   55  20
50
77

I can assign the first number to variable but cant read the other values

Comment: Post some code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can try assigning them to array

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

double arr1[size];

ifstream input("file.txt");

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    input >> arr1[i];
    cout<< arr1[i]<<std::endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Here you need to know the actual size, while using a vector (as in my answer below) can contain any number of values, thus when changing the file by for example adding or removing a value you don't need to edit the code

Answer (score 1):

You can read the other values, if you continue reading data. For example:

```
std::vector<float> data;

float x;
while(std::cin >> x)
{
   data.push_back(x);
}
```

Now you have a vector (see it as a normal array if you don't know what it is, or look at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)) which contains all the values you put in your text file.